# Populate a Checkbox list from a view model list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, list, checkbox, checkboxlist

I am trying to re define the select query and make it user defined by first listing out all the fields in one checkbox list and grouping them in another and providing a where condition for selected check boxed fields. I am returning a view model that contains the list of all my columns.
I need to know how to populate the list from my view model onto a asp.net checkbox list.

Thanks in advance,
Hrg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding try this

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.PropertyName.Count(); i++)
    {
        <p>
        @Html.CheckBox("model.PropertyName[" + i + "]", !Model.PropertyName[i])
        </p>
    }
```

Comment: Thanks AKA. I did something similar and manage to get what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You van use this also

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.PropertyName.Count(); i++)
{

```
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.Tags[i])
```

}